# VC++ Compile error on DLL project

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-errors

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" int __stdcall myfunction ();

BOOL WINAPI DllMain ( HINSTANCE hin, DWORD reason, LPVOID lpvReserved );

int __stdcall myfunction ()
{
      MessageBoxW(NULL,L"Question",L"Title",MB_OK);
      return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain ( HINSTANCE hin, DWORD reason, LPVOID lpvReserved )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

When i compile show these errors:

> error LNK2028: reference to simbol
>   (token) unresolved (0A000027) "extern "C" int **stdcall
>   MessageBoxW(struct HWND** *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned
>   int)"  (?MessageBoxW@@$$J216YGHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z) in the function
>   "extern "C" int __stdcall myfunction(void)" (?myfunction@@$$J10YGHXZ)
>
> error LNK2019: External symbol "extern "C" int **stdcall
>   MessageBoxW(struct HWND** *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned
>   int)" (?MessageBoxW@@$$J216YGHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z) unresolved used in
>   the function "extern "C" int __stdcall myfunction(void)"
>   (?myfunction@@$$J10YGHXZ)

I dont understand where is the error and their cause.
If someone can help me to fix it I will thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, but the problem was the user32.lib.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib"); //Missing lib (No compile errors)

BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    return  TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SomeFunction() {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello", "HELLO", 0x000000L); //0x000000L = MB_OK
}
```

I hope this gonna to be helpful for noobs like me.

Answer (score 0):

The `extern "C"` needs to be on the function, not the definition:

```
int __stdcall myfunction ();

extern "C" int __stdcall myfunction ()
{
      MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Question", L"Title", MB_OK);
      return 0;
}
```

however, instead of attaching `extern "C"` to it all, you could wrap it in a pre-parser conditional:

```
int __stdcall myfunction ();

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

int __stdcall myfunction ()
{
      MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Question", L"Title", MB_OK);
      return 0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Comment: This code return `error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'myfunction'`.